# Curves with constant curvature and constant torsion

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Describe all curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which have constant curvature $κ > 0$ and constant torsion $τ$.

Any ideas what we can do to describe all such curves?

Do we have to use the formulas of the curvature and of the torsion?

Comment: You *can* integrate the Frenet–Serret equations directly, which gives you the equation of the tangent vector up to a rotation, and therefore the curve up to an initial position (mind you, I didn't say you *should* do this...).

Comment: The Frenet-Serret equations are: 


$$\textbf{$\dot t$}=k\textbf{n} \\ \textbf{$\dot n$}=-k\textbf{t}+\tau \textbf{b} \\ \textbf{$\dot b$}=-\tau \textbf{n}$$ 

How can we integrate these equations? @Chappers

Comment: You can write them as a matrix differential equation for the matrix $( \mathbf{t,n,b} )^T$, and then integrate in the same way as a matrix DE acting on a vector: you end up with arbitrary vectors at $t=0$ instead of just one arbitrary vector (although you have to fulfil orthogonality, of course). You need the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), but constant curvature and torsion make the DE much easier to solve than usual.

Comment: Why was [my three-year-old question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197725/how-can-i-prove-that-a-curve-with-constant-nonzero-curvature-and-torsion-is-a-he) marked as a duplicate of this two-month-old one?

Answer (score 10):

As had been explained, you may choose to either solve the differential equation given by Frenet's identities in the space of matrices, or do the smart trick suggested by Ted Shiffrin; I shall choose the latter approach.

For my typing convenience, I shall also omit all the "mathhb" formatting, therefore the normal will just be $n$. Also, since $t$ is the tangent, I shall use $s$ for the time parameter on the curve.

Starting with $\ddot n = - (k^2 + \tau ^2)n$, we shall approach it in the usual way: first we consider its associated algebraic equation $\lambda ^2 = -(k^2 + \tau ^2)$, which has the roots $\pm \Bbb i \sqrt{k^2 + \tau ^2}$. Next, we know from the general theory of linear equations that this gives two fundamental solutions to the above equation, namely $u \sin rs$ and  $v \cos rs$ where $r^2 = k^2 + \tau ^2$ and $u,v \in \Bbb R ^3$ (note that $r \ne 0$ because $k>0$ by assumption). Therefore, $n(s) = u \sin rs + v \cos rs$ for some constant vectors $u,v \in \Bbb R ^3$.

May $u,v \in \Bbb R ^3$ be really arbitrary? Not quite: note that $n(0) = v$ and since $\| n (s) \| = 1 \ \forall s$ (the curve is parametrized by arc-length and the Frenet frame is taken to be orthonormal), then $\| v \| = 1$. Next, if you derive this once, you get $\dot n (0) = ru$; on the other hand, $\dot n (0) = -k t(0) + \tau b (0)$, so $r u = -k t(0) + \tau b (0)$, so $r^2 \| u \| ^2 = \| -k t(0) + \tau b (0) \| ^2 = k^2 \| t (0) \| ^2 - 2 k \tau \langle t(0), b(0) \rangle + \tau ^2 \| v \| ^2$. Since $\| t \| = \| b \| = 1$ and $\langle t, b \rangle = 0$, the last expression is exactly $k^2 + \tau ^2 = r^2$, which implies $\| u \| = 1$. Finally, $\| n \| ^2 = 1$ implies $\| u \| ^2 \sin ^2 rs + 2 \sin rs \cos rs \langle u, v \rangle + \| v \| ^2 \cos ^2 rs = 1$ which, taking into consideration all of the above, implies $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$. To conclude, $u$ and $v$ must be orthogonal, and of length $1$.

Next, if your curve is $s \mapsto x(s) \in \Bbb R ^3$ ($x$ is a vector, not the first coordinate of a vector!), then using the equation $\dot t = k n$ and the fact that $t = \dot x$, you will get $\ddot x = kn = k (u \sin rs + v \cos rs)$, that you will have to integrate twice. Integrating once gives $\dot x = -\dfrac k r u \cos rs + \dfrac k r v \sin rs + w$, with $w \in \Bbb R ^3$, and integrating once more gives $x = - \dfrac k {r^2} u \sin rs - \dfrac k {r^2} v \cos rs + ws + x_0$, with $x_0 \in \Bbb R^3$.

Similarly to the discussion about $u$ and $v$, may $w$ be arbitrary? No, it may not: first, $\langle t, n \rangle = 0$ implies $\langle w, u \sin rs + v \cos rs \rangle = 0 \ \forall s$, which implies that $w \perp \text{span} \{u, v \}$. Second, using this and the fact that $\| \dot x \| ^2 = \| t \| ^2 = 1$ implies that $\| w \| = \dfrac {| \tau |} r$. There is no constraint, on the other hand, on $x_0$.

If $\tau = 0$ (so your curve is a plane curve), after a possible orthogonal transformation you may take $u = (-1, 0, 0)$ and $v = (0, -1, 0)$, so your curve will look like $x(s) = (\dfrac k {r^2} \sin rs, \dfrac k {r^2} \cos rs, 0) + x_0$ which, after a translation by $x_0$ will have the final nice form $x(s) = (\dfrac k {r^2} \sin rs, \dfrac k {r^2} \cos rs, 0)$, so it will be a *circle*.

If $\tau \ne 0$, since $\{ -u, -v, w \frac r {\ |\tau| }\}$ have been shown to form an orthonormal frame (in fact, we have worked with $u$ and $v$, but absorbing a minus sign into them doesn't change orthonormality), after a possible orthogonal transformation you may take them to form the familiar frame $\{ (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) \}$, in which case you curve looks like $x(s) = (\dfrac k {r^2} \sin rs, \dfrac k {r^2} \cos rs, \frac {| \tau |} r s) + x_0$. If you also translate your curve by $x_0$ (again, this doesn't change your curve), it will have the final nice form $x(s) = (\dfrac k {r^2} \sin rs, \dfrac k {r^2} \cos rs, s\dfrac { |\tau | } r)$, which is a *helix*. Note that this equation reduces to the one of the circle for $\tau \to 0$.

Therefore, the only curves that satisfy your problem are circles and helices. (Had you allowed $k=0$ too, you would have also obtained (segments of) straight lines).

Comment: We have 
$$t=\dot x = -\dfrac k r u \cos rs + \dfrac k r v \sin rs + w
$$ 

$$n(s) = u \sin rs + v \cos rs
$$ 

Which is the formula of 
$$\langle t, n \rangle $$ ?

Comment: @user159870: I am not sure that I understand your question properly: $\langle t, n \rangle = 0$ trivially by the definition of $n$.

Comment: I understood this part. But I am facing some difficulties understanding the following part: $$$$ "If $\tau = 0$ (so your curve is a plane curve), after a possible orthogonal transformation you may take $u = (-1, 0, 0)$ and $v = (0, -1, 0)$, so your curve will look like $x(s) = (\dfrac k {r^2} \sin rs, \dfrac k {r^2} \cos rs, 0) + x_0$ which, after a translation by $x_0$ will have the final nice form $x(s) = (\dfrac k {r^2} \sin rs, \dfrac k {r^2} \cos rs, 0)$, so it will be a *circle*."
$$$$ What do you mean by "after a translation by $x_0$" ? Do we set $x_0=0$ ?

Comment: @user159870: Exactly, if you want your result to look nicer you may define a new (translated) curve $\bar x = x - x_0$. Note that this wouldn't change anything in the computations above, because derivatives would just kill $x_0$, so $\dot {\bar x} = \dot x$.

Comment: I understand. Do we take these $u$ and $v$ so that they satisfy the condition that they are orthonormal?

Comment: @user159870: Yes, we have already proven that they are arthogonal and of length $1$, so what better choice than that one? (The minus sign is there only to get a nice final result, otherwise it plays no role.)

Comment: I understand. Why does $\langle w, u \sin rs + v \cos rs \rangle = 0 \ \forall s
$ imply that $w \perp \text{span} \{u, v \}
$?

Comment: Also do we have to determine at the end which the curvature and the torsion is at each case?

Comment: @user159870: Take $s=0$ in that equality; this will produce $\langle w, v \rangle = 0$, so $w \perp v$. Next, using this, that equality simplifies to $\langle w, u \rangle \sin rs = 0 \ \forall s$ so now choose some $s$ with $\sin rs \ne 0$ in order to get $\langle w, u \rangle = 0$, so $w \perp u$. Since $w \perp v$ and $w \perp u$, it is immediate that $w \perp \text{span} \{u, v\}$. It is not necessary to compute the curvature and the torsion at the end, but you may do it using the standard formulae if you feel like.

Comment: To compute the curvature do we use the formula $$\kappa=\|\ddot x\|$$ ?  But how can we do that when at the formula of $x$ we have $\kappa$ ?

Comment: @AlexM. Shouldn't it be $\|w\| = \frac{|k|}{r}$?

Comment: @AaronMaroja: No, it's $\tau$, but your comment made me reread my answer and find some typographical errors in the 4th paragraph. Anyway, norm-squaring $\dot x = - \dfrac k r u \cos rs + \dfrac k r v \sin rs + w$ gives $1 = \dfrac {k^2} {r^2} \cos^2 rs + \dfrac {k^2} {r^2} \sin^2 rs + \| w \| ^2 = \dfrac {k^2} {r^2} + \| w \| ^2$ and now use $r^2 = k^2 + \tau ^2$.

Comment: a small unimportant question: why do you write $|\tau|$ and not $\tau$? Isn't $\tau$ already a number?

Comment: @Whyka: $|\tau|$ is the absolute value of $\tau$.

Comment: @AlexM. Ah, okay. So you want to take the positive value of $\tau$. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**HINT**: If you don't want to solve the matrix differential equation, I recommend that you get a *second*-order differential equation for the principal normal $n$. You should know solutions of this by sight (at least, component by component).

Comment: We have $$\textbf{$\dot t$}=k\textbf{n} \\ \textbf{$\dot n$}=-k\textbf{t}+\tau \textbf{b} \\ \textbf{$\dot b$}=-\tau \textbf{n}$$ 

Differentiating the second equations we get 
$$\textbf{$\ddot n$}=-k\textbf{$\dot t$}+\tau \textbf{$\dot b$}\Rightarrow \textbf{$\ddot n$}=-k^2\textbf{n}-\tau^2 \textbf{n} \Rightarrow \textbf{$\ddot n$}=-(k^2+\tau^2) \textbf{n}$$ What do we do next?

Comment: @user159870, don't you know the general solution of $y''+\lambda^2 y=0$?

Answer (score 3):

From the Fresnet-Serret formulas, we can derive

$$\ddddot\gamma(s)=\kappa\ddot n(s)=-\kappa(\kappa^2+\tau^2)n(s)=-a^2\ddot\gamma(s),$$ with $a=\sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}$.

The general solution for this fourh order linear equation is
$$\color{green}{\gamma(s)=C\cos(as)+S\sin(as)+C_1s+C_0},$$ 
which describes an elliptic helix.

Anyway, computing the curvature for any $s$ (such as $s=0,s=\dfrac\pi{2a}$),

$$\kappa=\|\dot t(s)\|=\|\ddot\gamma(s)\|=a^2\|C\cos(as)+S\sin(as)\|,$$

we must have
$$\|C\|=\|S\|=\frac\kappa{a^2}\text{, and }C\cdot S=0$$ for the curvature to be constant (the normal vector describes a circle).

Similarly,

$$\kappa\tau=\|\kappa\dot n(s)+\kappa^2t(s)\|=\|\ddot t(s)+\kappa^2t(s)\|=\|-a\tau^2(C\cos(as)+S\sin(as))+\kappa^2C_1\|$$ requires $$C\cdot C_1=S\cdot C_1=0\text{, and }\|C_1\|=\frac{\tau\kappa}a$$ (the tangent vectors describes a circular cone).

Hence the curve is a *circular* helix.

Comment: Why do we require the following? $$$$ 

$$\kappa=\|\dot t(s)\|=\|\ddot\gamma(s)\|=a^2\|C\cos(as)+S\sin(as)\|,$$

we must have
$$C\cdot S=0$$ for the curvature to be constant. 

Why does this stand:  "the normal vector describes a circle" ? 



$$\kappa\tau=\|\kappa\dot n(s)+\kappa^2t(s)\|=\|\ddot t(s)+\kappa^2t(s)\|=\|-a\tau^2(C\cos(as)+S\sin(as))+\kappa^2C_1\|$$ requires $$C\cdot C_1=S\cdot C_1=0\text{, and }\|C_1\|=\frac{\tau\kappa}a$$  

Why does this stand: "the tangent vectors describes a circular cone" ?

Comment: @user159870 We must ensure that the curvature and torsion are constant ! (The geometric interpretations are just hints, not part of the proof.)

Comment: The curve is a circular helix *or* a circle (the problem allows for null torsion). (My remark is moot if you consider the circle to be a particular case of a helix.)

Comment: @AlexM: yes, a circle is an helix in flatland.