# Identifying curves using Frenet-Serret apparatus

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

I have a question about identifying regular curves in $ R^3 $ using Frenet-Serret apparatus. Considering the congruence of curves every unit-speed curves are congruent when they have same curvature and torsion.
Now I have a simple question. I wonder this is possible approach to prove the following

> $ \alpha $ is a curve with $ \kappa >0 \ $and $ \tau \ $ both constant. Show that $ \alpha $ is a circular helix

(This is the problem in the O'neil's Differential  Geometry textbook)

I think regular curves are always can be reparametrized to be a unit-speed curve and after the reparametrization, reparametrized  $ \kappa \ $and $ \tau $ still have the same property with $\alpha $ , so I can construct the circular helix with same curvature and torsion. Thus by the congruence argument, $ \alpha $ is also a circular helix.

I doubt my argument at some points.

1. Is it possible to define a helix with any constant $ \kappa >0 $ and  $ \tau $ ?
2. Can I argue that original $ \alpha $ is circular helix when its unit-speed reparametrization is circular helix(I think this is possible since their image is eqaul...)

And finally I wonder there is another way to prove this problem. I think I can use the cross-sectional curve of the cylinder (Since the fact $ \alpha $ is a cylindrical helix is trivial.), but I don't know how can I use this....

Please show me the right way to solve problems like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curves with constant curvature and constant torsion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469521/curves-with-constant-curvature-and-constant-torsion)

Comment: Although clearly related, the proposed duplicate seems to me to have a somewhat different motivation.