# Given a curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$, find a regular curve with such (Solving Frenet Serret equations)

Tags: differential-geometry

$T'=\kappa N$

$N'=-\kappa T + \tau B$

$B' = -\kappa N$

How do I find the curve given the Frenet-serret equations, $\tau$ and $\kappa$? Is this purely a differential equations question at this point? If so, could somebody walk me through it? My knowledge on the subject is extremely limited. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some example in mind?

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem!

Comment: Are $\kappa>0$ and $\tau$ constant in this case? If so, this is covered in e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1469521/169085.